# How to calculate Quarterly fund returns?

Tags: excel, vba

Hope everyone is doing okay and keeping safe

I have been tasked to make a Fund Performance dashboard using VBA
I am able to get stock data from yahoo. Also managed to calcuated monthly returns from daily NAVs.
However I am struggling to calculate Quarterly returns.

Here is the code. Though this works in calculating quarterly returns the issue is it repeats. Here is a picture (practice file cant mention real returns)

[It calculates the monthly returns, but for quarterly retuns I only want for actual quarter ends in a financial year in a year. However here is it calculating for every month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGRg1.png)

If anyone can guide me it can be of great help. Thanks

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Worksheets("Prac").Activate

            
  Dim old_ As Double
  Dim new_ As Double
  Dim start_row As Integer
  start_row = 4

  ' Track the number of rows
   Dim num_row As Integer
   num_row = 0
   While (Not (IsEmpty(Cells(start_row + num_row, "G"))) And Not (IsEmpty(Cells(start_row + 
   num_row, "G"))))
   num_row = num_row + 3
 Wend

 Dim end_row As Integer
 end_row = num_row + start_row - 1
' Calculate Rate of Return
Dim m_r_j As Double
Dim m_r_m As Double

For r = start_row To end_row - 3 Step 1
 old_ = Cells(r, "G")
 new_ = Cells(r + 3, "G")

 m_r_j = (new_ - old_) / old_
 Cells(r + 3, "M").Value = m_r_j

 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Without dissecting your code, it looks like you need to check, for quarterly returns, that the date is an end of quarter date; otherwise return a blank.

Comment: Yes, so say i have monthly prices from April till September - so it would show quaterly return using April to July and July to September prices only

Comment: Yes, just add that check to your existing code, where it is presently calculating the quarterly returns, and it should work.

Comment: Hey Ron, I am not able to understand how to excute that code. Can you please guide me

Comment: Which line of your code is presently returning the quarterly numbers?

Comment: Cells(r + 3, "M").Value = m_r_j this one

Comment: Probably something like `if(Cells(r + 3, "whatever column the date is in") = "end of qtr date" then Cells(r + 3, "M").Value = m_r_j`